# Almacenar contraseña descifrable - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, api, autenticación, contraseña

Estoy realizando una plataforma, la cual consume una API externa en el momento en que el usuario inicia sesión. Sin embargo, para consumir dicha API hay que obtener un token mediente usuario y contraseña. El problema es que dichos datos no los debe conocer el usuario (por requerimiento) y no sé cómo almacenar la contraseña para la API, teniendo en cuenta que si uso `password_hash()` no tendré la contraseña original, únicamente el hash.

Investigué y vi que cifrar la clave en AES-256 puede ser una buena opción, pero no estoy muy seguro. ¿Cómo puedo almacenar dicha clave?

Comment: debes crear tu propio metodo de encriptacion ..

Comment: aqui tienes un ejemplo: http://www.juntadeandalucia.es/servicios/madeja/contenido/recurso/583

Comment: Tu idea es que al iniciar sesión el usuario reciba el token de vuelta para acceder al API desde el browser? El token no contiene la contraseña así que por ese lado no hay problema. Ahora, he de suponer que lo que quieres es descifrar la contraseña para obtener un token sin interacción del usuario de ahí en adelante. Es eso lo que necesitas? El password en tu BBDD es el mismo que usa el API?

Comment: Tu descripción es acertada y es justo mi situación. Tanto el usuario como el password son diferentes entre la plataforma y la API. Tegito123, gracias, sin embargo la función de ese tutorial está depreciada en la doc de php :/